# how to set the link at end of the columns in datagrid in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

presently i working on win forms(code behind c#) in this i'm using data-grid and i keep the link in datagrid. My question is when i keep the links in grid it will show at first columns but i want these links show at last columns of the grid please anybody help me.......
how to getting this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Column7"].DisplayIndex = dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1;
```

Here Column7 is your *DataGridViewLinkColumn* and by setting the **DisplayIndex** you determine the position which now would be the last column.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for giving response can u explain little bit, means where i can write this code...please

Comment: You can write this after assigning the DataSource if any to the Grid or in the Form Load event