# Creating column Combobox in Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am new to `C#`. I want to create `combobox` in first column of my `Datagridview`. Following is the routine I have wrote. But it is adding combo in last column after setting up my grid.

For setting up Grid, i have tried the below code:

```
private void SetGrid()
{
    dgDetail.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dgDetail.ColumnCount = 5;
    dgDetail.Columns[0].Name = "Debit";
    dgDetail.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Debit Account Name";
    dgDetail.Columns[1].Name = "Bank";
    dgDetail.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Bank";
    dgDetail.Columns[2].Name = "ChqNo";
    dgDetail.Columns[2].HeaderText = "CC/Chq No";
    dgDetail.Columns[3].Name = "ChqDate";
    dgDetail.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Chq Date";
    dgDetail.Columns[4].Name = "Amount";
    dgDetail.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Amount";
    dgDetail.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;
    dgDetail.Columns[0].Width = 280;
    dgDetail.Columns[1].Width = 160;
    dgDetail.Columns[2].Width = 90;
    dgDetail.Columns[3].Width = 90;
    dgDetail.Columns[4].Width = 120;
    dgDetail.RowsDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    dgDetail.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    dgDetail.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular);
}
```

For Creating the combobox which is filled from DB.

```
private void FillGridCombo()
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strCon);
    sqlConnection.Open();
    try
    {
        string selectQueryStringMonth = "SELECT accode, GLAC FROM glmast where (actype = 'CSH' and titleac <> 'PDP') OR TITLEAC = 'DIS' ORDER BY GLAC";

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQueryStringMonth, sqlConnection);
        SqlCommandBuilder sqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapter);

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        BindingSource bindingSourceMonth = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;

        //Adding  Combo
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ColumnAcc = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        ColumnAcc.DataPropertyName = "Debit Account Name";
        ColumnAcc.HeaderText = "Debit Account Name";
        ColumnAcc.Width = 280;

        ColumnAcc.DataSource = bindingSourceMonth;
        ColumnAcc.ValueMember = "accode";
        ColumnAcc.DisplayMember = "GLAC";

        dgDetail.Columns.Add(ColumnAcc);
        dgDetail.DataSource = bindingSource;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    finally
    {
        if (sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

I am calling both procedures on my NewData() like this.

```
private void NewData()
{
    if (dgDetail.DataSource != null)
        dgDetail.DataSource = null;
    else
        dgDetail.Rows.Clear();

    ClearData();
    CtrlEnable();
    SetGrid();
    FillGridCombo();
}
```

Help / Guide me to achieve this.,

Comment: You can also control it by setting the [DisplayIndex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854807/how-to-set-the-link-at-end-of-the-columns-in-datagrid-in-winforms/5855091#5855091) property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Insert` method instead of `Add` like this:

```
dgDetail.Columns.Insert(0,ColumnAcc);
```

Comment: One more thing. When I select value in a combobox, it does shows the value on first selection. It shows me on second time selection. Also how can i focus on combo while navigating through columns?

Comment: @Raja what do you mean by `navigating through columns`? by selecting column? Could you make it clear? I don't get well what the next problem you have.

Comment: I mean by selecting columns.

Comment: @Raja when you select a column by clicking on its header, **you can't focus any cell**, why do you want to focus some cell when selecting column? selecting column is done mainly before we're trying to **set some options** for the selected column such as `hide the column`.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
dgDetail.Columns.Insert(0, ColumnAcc);
```

instead of

```
dgDetail.Columns.Add(ColumnAcc);
```

when you use `Add` it simply adds it as the last column, while using [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.insert.aspx) you can choose where to add it to.

> public virtual void Insert(   int columnIndex,    DataGridViewColumn
>   dataGridViewColumn )

note that the `columnIndex` is a zero-based index so 0 is the first column