# c# datagridview Combobox Column Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, combobox

I'm getting this Error: “DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.”
here is my code

```
 DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvcombo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                            dgvcombo.ValueType = typeof(decimal);
                            dgvcombo.Name = Name;
                            dgvcombo.DataPropertyName = colname;
                            dgvcombo.DataSource = dtsource;
                            dgvcombo.DisplayMember = DisplayMember;
                            dgvcombo.ValueMember = ValueMember;
                            dgvcombo.Visible = Visible;
                            dgvcombo.Width = width;
                            DataGridView.Columns.Add(dgvcombo);
```

I get this error everytime a Combobox column is generated for all the rows

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvcombo =
            dataGridView1.Columns[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
```

or you can try this 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753687/datagridviewcomboboxcell-setting-value-manually-value-not-valid/3139562#3139562) also

Comment: which cell you want to display in combobox give that cell value i.e index

Comment: 3 cells, columns Number(2,3,4)

Comment: try for 2 
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvcombo =
            dataGridView1.Columns[2] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;

Comment: I didn't write 0 I Changed the number of course, but I got index out of range error.

Comment: You can use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087960/creating-column-combobox-in-datagridview

Comment: set AutoGenerateColumns = false for datagridview